# HtmlUnit: trying to scrape AngularJS webpage

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, htmlunit

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit to scrape the content of a Website.
I am able to programmatically login to my account, but most of the content on the client-side is generated using Javascript (Angular JS). So my questions are:

1. Can we use HTMLUnit to scrape this page using Angular JS as the scripting language.
2. This is my code:

```java
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
WebClientOptions webClientOptions = webClient.getOptions();
webClientOptions.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(//url);
final HtmlForm form2 = page2.getFormByName("login");
final HtmlSubmitInput button = form2.getInputByValue("Sign In");
final HtmlTextInput textField = form2.getInputByName("email");
textField.setValueAttribute("//email");
final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form2.getInputByName("login_password");
textField2.setValueAttribute(//password); 
final HtmlPage page3 = button.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: PS: I get a lot of javascript errors.

Comment: Please provide the URL you use, so others can see the errors

Comment: --Solved Hey thanks a lot for your reply Ahmed. I found a work around to my problem.

Comment: What would that workaround be, @Nachiket ?  You should post an answer to your own question so others can benefit.

Comment: Hi @MichaelOryl: Well i was able to get to the login page and complete the login functionality by using the above code.

Comment: Hi @MichaelOryl: Well i was able to get to the login page and complete the login functionality by using the above code. But there was a problem. The website I was trying to use was using server side JS to load the content. So I dropped to idea of scrapping the page. When I said I found a work around to the problem, all I meant was that I was able to complete the login functionality by using the above code.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Appreciate it.